# AWS-EKS kubernetes cluster: Redis keys are deleted automatically after few min

Tags: redis, amazon-eks

I have AWS cluster enviornment, where I have added 3 nodes and deployed Redis and insrted some data in redis. But after few mins data is getting deleted automatically. Note: There is no expiry set on any key.

And when this data is removed from from redis, I can see some keys with name as a backup in redis
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YVeOO.png)

Note: Redis data persistency is already on.

Anyone have any idea, what could be the issue?